# =CONCAT(***-**-,RIGHT(J8, 4)) not working in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=CONCAT(***-**-,RIGHT(J8,4)) [image of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msNqL.png)

I entered the code above and it showed error

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Try `=CONCAT(H15 & "**--**",RIGHT(J8,4))`

Comment: Are you masking an actual number perhaps?

Comment: @soham-phargade I have posted it as answer so that you can accept it (tick mark the answer) to treat the thread as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may use below formula-

```
=CONCAT(H15 & "**--**",RIGHT(J8,4))
```